# WPF Button does not react to any event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I've got a simple WPF Window, pretty simple, a `TextBlock` and a `Button`.
However the button does not react to anything. Not if I move my mouse over it nor if I click it.

Line from the Button:

```
<Button Margin="3" Command="Close" Content="Ok" Width="50"/>
```

Full Window Code:

```
<Window x:Class="Launcher.XAML.MessageWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="self"
    Title="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=Caption}" Height="194" Width="477">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=Message}" Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Margin="3" Command="Close" Content="Ok" Width="50"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: And how do you expect it to react?

Comment: Presumably with some kind of visual change as a mouse over / click occurs. At least, that is my assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify your CommandBindings and Button like so:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"
                Executed="CloseCommandHandler"
                CanExecute="CanExecuteHandler"
                />
</Window.CommandBindings>

....

<Button Margin="3" Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" Content="Ok" Width="50"/>
```

And then setup your  Executed and CanExecute handlers:

```
private void CloseCommandHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do something
}

private void CanExecuteHandler(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Determine whether handler can execute
    e.CanExecute = true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea, was the CanExecute handler.. Also, it was one of that standart commands wpf overs so i needed to write my own.

Comment: You can shorten `ApplicationCommands.Close` to `Close` in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what's in your Styles.xaml. Try commenting that out and see if it then works.

Answer (score 0):

There migth be a problem with the binding to the Close command. Things to look in to (and perhaps show us) :

- that the DataContext of the view is set properly
- how the Command returned by the Close property in the viewmodel is implemented...